# Filter Observable<List> with text from an EditText using RxBinding

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

I have an array of Objects and I want to filter that array based on the text user types on an `EditText` android view.

What I thought it that I should try and convert the array of POJOs to an Observable of Strings and this is what I did :

```
    Observable<String> professionsObservable = Observable.fromArray(((GetStartedActivity) getActivity()).professions)
            .map(profession -> {
                if (profession.getName().length() > 0) {
                    professionsNameList.add(capitalizeFirstLetter(profession.getName()));
                }

                return professionsNameList;
            })
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items);
```

Now I want to combine the text from the `EditText` with the `professionsObservable I posted above.

This is the code I'm using :

```
    RxTextView.textChangeEvents(etProfession)
            .doOnEach(notif -> {
                if (etProfession.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    etCompany.setVisibility(GONE);
                    etIndustry.setVisibility(GONE);
                } else {
                    etCompany.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    etIndustry.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            })
            .debounce(EDITTEXT_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .skip(1)
            .map(textChangeEvent -> textChangeEvent.text().toString())
            .switchMap(search -> {
                return professionsObservable
                        .filter(profession -> {
                            return profession.toLowerCase().startsWith(search);
                        });
                    }
            )
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    filteredProfessions -> {
                        Timber.i("NOT ENTERING");
                        rvProfession.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        professionAdapter.addItems(filteredProfessions);
                    },
                    throwable -> Log.i("THROW", "PROFESSIONS ", throwable));
```

I'm using `map` operator to turn the text change event to a String and then for each String I get from the stream I'm using `switchMap` (cause I don't care for results from previous searches). Then I compose all Strings to a List with `toList`. The problem is that it never reaches the `subscribe` call while I have a lot of strings in the initial Array I used and I do type text that fits the condition of the `filter` operator.

Is it something that I might missing here ?

EDIT : I updated my code to :

```
        RxTextView.textChangeEvents(etProfession)
            .doOnEach(notif -> {
                if (etProfession.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    etCompany.setVisibility(GONE);
                    etIndustry.setVisibility(GONE);
                } else {
                    etCompany.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    etIndustry.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .debounce(EDITTEXT_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .skip(1)
            .map(textChangeEvent -> textChangeEvent.text().toString())
            .flatMap(search -> {
                return Observable.fromArray(((GetStartedActivity) getActivity()).professions)
                        .map(profession -> {
                            List<String> professionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (profession.getName().length() > 0) {
                                professionsList.add(capitalizeFirstLetter(profession.getName()));
                            }
                            return professionsList;
                        })
                        .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
                        .filter(profession -> {
                            if (profession.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                            }

                            return profession.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase());
                        });
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    filteredProfessions -> {
                        rvProfession.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
             //        professionAdapter.addItems(filteredProfessions);
                    },
                    throwable -> Log.i("THROW", "PROFESSIONS ", throwable));
```

If I remove `toList()`  operator my code works (enters the `subscribe` call) but if I leave it there it wont. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3861#issuecomment-210899851)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, *RxBinding* requires *.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())* right after *.textChangeEvents()* or any other event. So probably you are causing it to fail by adding *.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)*

See method *.checkMainThread()* in https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/internal/Preconditions.java

**UPDATE**

Also, probably because *.onComplete()* never comes from upstream, *.toList()* is never executed.

Comment: I did what you said but still the same result. I'm also logging in case of an exception so I think if there was an `IllegalStateException` I would see it on logcat.

Comment: Ah, then it is probably because *.onComplete()* never comes from upstream *.toList()* is never executed.